Skip some bytes from the beginning of a PDF stream
I want to convert some JPEG and PNG files to PDF, but I want to do it in a way that the original files are easily recoverable. This is easy for JPEG files: they get embedded directly in an stream object, so you can recover a bit identical copy of them.
In principle, this is impossible with PNG files because the PDF specification defines its own lossless image compression format instead of embedding PNG files as in the case of JPEG.
However, if there were a way to convince the PDF browser to skip the first N bytes of data of an stream, it would be possible to embed some unmodified PNG files in the image stream and the image should read correctly.
In some cases, the compressed image stream starting on the 8th byte of the IDATA chunk (if there is only one, there is no alpha channel and the image is gray or RGB) is compatible with the compressed image stream defined by the PDF specification. In addition, a conformant deflate decompressor ignores any trailing data on a valid compressed stream, so the remaining bytes of the PNG file wouldn't interfere in the correct parsing of the image stream. The only problem is the leading bytes of the PNG image.
Is there a way to skip some bytes from the beginning of a PDF stream?

In NodeJS you can use some libs, like https://github.com/sindresorhus/read-chunk (its pretty simple under hood). You didn't specify the tools you use for generation, so I suggest using a system I'm familiar with)

The PDF spec does not have an option for ignoring the first bytes of a steam. But you could split your PDF in 3 parts, use the center part as your image stream and add entries with the order parts to the image stream dictionary.

@mkl That's plan B. I wrote here to se if someone smarter than me can come up with some trick abusing the spec or Flate/LZW/RunLengthDecode filter properties (similar to the fact that decompressors of zlib stream ignore remaining trailing data after the adler32 checksum).

"similar to the fact that decompressors of zlib stream ignore remaining trailing data after the adler32 checksum" - I recommend not to make use of such tricks. If validator software ever is to take a look at PDFs with such extra bytes, it might warn about non-conform image streams with extra (hidden?) data. Depending on the context that might cause trouble.

@KJ Proper lossless JPEG isn't widely supported, and JPEG with quality 100 generates files much larger than PNG for images with large areas of flat colors. Moreover, my goal is to preserve the original unmodified file as can be done with JPEG.

@mkl I fully agree with you that abusing the spec is a bad idea for any other file format in existence, but for PDF... parsing PDF is the wild west. The de facto standard implementation, Acrobat Reader, accepts almost anything you throw to it, so most viewers are forced to be very lax. Antivirus and other security oriented verifiers that can complain about it are not an issue in my case: it is for personal use, converting a bunch of images in a format easy to handle and highly compatible with my devices while preserving the original unmodified files.
